# Send Nested JSON from view to model

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, rest

I want to send Nested JSON from view to model, there are other questions about this problem but none of them have variable keys in their object.

JSON object:

```
"Login": {
    "userId": "harshal.bulsara",
    "userName": "Harshal Bulsara",
 },


"ListOfEntities": {
       "Patient": {
            0: "Add",
            1: "Edit"
          },
       "Practice": {
            0: "Add",
            1: "Edit",
            2: "List"
         },
   }
```

I was able to send data with key Login properly but I am not able to send ListOfEntities, **Important thing here is that the key inside this JSON will not be same every time (Patient,practice) it may vary**

Here is the model code:

```
public class authoritiesInfo
{
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int,string>> ListOfEntities { get; set; }
}
public class dashboardModel
{
    public string userId { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }

    public List<authoritiesInfo> auth { get; set; }
    public void createSession()
    {
        processing //
    }

}
```

Here is the controller code:

```
public class DashboardController : Controller
{
    // GET: Dashboard
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(dashboardModel dm)
    {
        dm.createSession();
        return View();
    }
}
```

Code in view:

```
 var dt = [];
        dt.push({
            "userId": indexValue.value,
            "userName": $("#cmbName option:selected").text(),
            "auth": MY JSON mention above
        });


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Dashboard")',
            data: dt[0],
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function (data) {
               window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Page", "Dashboard")';
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
```

**Question**: How can I send Nested JSON to controller, The JSON is coming from REST service which is also in my control of if there are other solution which required any modification in that is also welcome

Comment: That's not even valid JSON :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, You think I need to change JSON altogether?

Comment: Yes. But its not clear what you trying to bind to. Are you saying that you can have a collection with values such as "Patient", "Practice" and other 'keys' and each of those contains a collection of values such as "Add", "Edit" etc? It also does not make sense that you using ajax to post data and then redirecting in the callback

Comment: Yes, there are collection of values such as patients, practice the list can change, I can change the implementation if you have anything else in mind for posting data

Comment: Just means changing your model to say `public class authoritiesInfo { public string Name { get; set; } public List<string> Values { get; set; } }` and then it would be `data: JSON.stringify({ userId: xxx, userName: xxx, auth: [{ Name: "Patient", Values: ["Add", "Edit"] }, { Name: "Practice",  Values: [....] } ]}),` and set the `contentType: 'json'` option. But where do those values for `auth` come from. If they are from form controls, then its simply a matter of generating the view correctly and using `$('form').serialize()`

Comment: No its coming from Rest API

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I have updated the JSON as per your suggestion.It is working you can add as answer so I can accept it for our future users :)

Comment: I just gave a simplified example (and was not sure what you could change and what was fixed). Did you also want the `int` value (i.e. `0: 'Edit', 1: 'Edit'`) as well (rather than just a `List<string>`)?

Comment: No I update json with Name:"paitent", value:"edit,add,list"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to bind to JSON, you must set the `contentType: 'application/json'` ajax option and stringify your data using `JSON.stringify()`.

However, the `JavaScriptSerializer` wont bind nested Dictionaries, so you will change your model(s) to accept nested Lists

```
public class authoritiesInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Values { get; set; }
}
public class dashboardModel
{
    public string userId { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public List<authoritiesInfo> auth { get; set; }
}
```

and the data will then be

```
var data = {
    userId: 'harshal.bulsara',
    userName: 'Harshal Bulsara',
    auth: [
        {
            Name: 'Patient',
            Values: [ 'Add', 'Edit' ]
        },
        {
            Name: 'Practice',
            Values: ['Add', 'Edit', 'List']
        }
    ]
};
```

and the ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Dashboard")',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ dm: data }),
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        ....
    }
});
```

which will then bind to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(dashboardModel dm)
```

Side note: If you need a collection of objects such as `[{ 0: 'Add' },{ 1, 'Edit' }]` rather than a collection of strings `[ 'Add', 'Edit' ]`, then create an additional class (say `Item`) with properties `int ID` and `string Name` then change `public List<string> Values { get; set; }` to `public List<Item> Values { get; set; }` and change the data to

```
Name: 'Patient',
Values: [
    { ID: 2, Name: 'Add' },
    { ID: 3, Name: 'Edit' },
]
```